# Python Decorators & Nested Functions return statement. Proper usage with parenthesis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, python-decorators

What's the difference including/not including the parentheses on the `return` statement for inner function for decorators (and any nested functions)? Are the parenthesis only required if the function returns more than 1 variable?

In the example below I know this won't work unless I use `return inner()`, but I see other examples that don't use the `()` on the `return` and they work fine.

Terminology behind the reason would great so help me fully understand. Thanks.

```
def stars(func):
    def inner():
        print("*" * 50)
        func()
        print("*" * 50)
    return inner()

@stars
def func():
    print('Decorate this message.')
```

It initially prints my message, decorated. But if I call func() again, it will not print anything.

Another working example, but `return inner` works fine in this case, long as I have set up my function to support a callable variable, being `msg` for my example:

```
def star(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("*" * 30)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("*" * 30)
    return inner

@star
def func(msg):
    print(msg)
func("Another message to be decorated")
```

And I can call func('my new message') each time to print my message, decorated. Why is this compared to the previous example when I don't use a callable function?

Comment: Updated my question with another example, with a working 'return inner' with no parenthesis. Hope that helps make more sense.

Comment: The important point is that the decorator `@deco` prior to `def fun:...` is semantic sugar for `fun = deco(fun)` appearing right after the end of the `def`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a decorator you should not do `return inner()`

That would mean you are replacing the decorated func with the result of calling the wrapped func

Your code will *immediately* print the modified message, without you even trying to call `func()`!!

```
**************************************************
Decorate this message.
**************************************************
```

But that is not what is intended when you decorate a function.

You intend to modify the behaviour of the function, but you still expect to have to call the function manually.

That is why the code should be:

```
def stars(func):
    def inner():
        print("*" * 50)
        func()
        print("*" * 50)
    return inner

@stars
def func():
    print('Decorate this message.')

func()
**************************************************
Decorate this message.
**************************************************
```

To explain further:

When you use the decorator syntax

```
@stars
def func():
```

You are telling python to do the following:

```
func = stars(func)
```

In other words, `def func` but replace the function with the result of calling `stars(func)`

You might find it less confusing if you don't reuse the name `func` in the code. For example:

```
def stars(func):
    def inner():
        print("*" * 50)
        func()
        print("*" * 50)
    return inner

@stars
def print_a_message():
    print('Decorate this message.')

print_a_message()
**************************************************
Decorate this message.
**************************************************
```

Maybe it's clearer now that when we do `return inner` from the decorator we are telling Python to *replace* `print_a_message` with `inner`

Comment: Understood. When is it a good time to use `return some_inner_fucntion()`, with parenthesis? Any easy example?

Comment: @tdm basically, never (in the context of decorators... there are infinite uses for it in other python code)

Comment: Gooot it. Fully realizing how `stars()` basically builds and returns the nested function `inner()`to be called later. Yet I was returning the returned value from inner() immediately by mistake when I was using `return func()`. Not `return inner` Makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By calling the `inner` function, instead of returning the function object, `func` is called at decoration time.

```
stars(func) -> inner() -> func() # with some side effects
```

Which is usually not what we want. The function is decorated to be called at a later time.

More so, in the case when your **function takes argument(s)**, this is certainly not going work, as you'll need to actually call the decorated function with valid parameters to have them passed to `inner` and then on to `func`.

Answer (score 1):

Your invoking the `inner` function instead of returning it. The code below wraps the `func` function instead of calling it immediately like the code you've pasted above.

```
def stars(func):
    def inner():
        print("*" * 50)
        func()
        print("*" * 50)
    return inner

@stars
def func():
    print('Decorate this message.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with the parenthesis, you are not returning the decorator function. Rather, you are returning the *return value* of the function, which means you prematurely call the decorated function. If you didn't have parenthesis, your code would work correctly, and the function object `inner` would be returned.

In short, don't call the function. You need to return the actual function itself for your decorator to work correctly:

```
>>> def stars(func):
        def inner():
            print("*" * 50)
            func()
            print("*" * 50)
        return inner # Don't call inner, return it.

>>> @stars
def func():
    print('Decorate this message.')


>>> func()
**************************************************
Decorate this message.
**************************************************
>>>
```

If you called `inner` anyway, Your message would've been printed when `func()` was defined instead of `func()` being called.

Comment: "Rather, you are returning the return value of the function" - This helped click for me. Thank you!